# Storing streaming data into mongodb using nodejs the right way

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, database-design

### Where I'm At

I'm working on a streaming data pipeline currently for iot data which I read in nodejs application from a kinesis data stream.

I've data coming in from over 200+ different sensors at every 10 seconds. I batch the data in nodejs before writing it to the mongodb.

I have a 3 collection structure in mongoDB to store this data which aims to flexible data-schema which goes as follows :-

```
Datasource collection:- 
_id: ObjectId("1234567890abcdef12345678"),
name: "sensor-1"

Variables collection:- 
_id: ObjectId("234567890abcdef12345678"), // a unique id for each variable for a datasource
dataSourceId: ObjectId("1234567890abcdef12345678"),
variable: "temperature"

Values collection
_id: ObjectId("4567890abcdef12345678"),
variableId: ObjectId("234567890abcdef12345678"),
value: 25
timestamp : <timestamp
```

I've designed it on this principle :-

```
Data Sources that have Variables
Variables that have some Values
Values are time-stamped data points containing the information of a sensor .
```

Here is how the payload would look like :-

```
{
    "temperature" : 123,
    "humidity" : 32,
    "current" : 2,
    "voltage" : 23.23,
    "power" : 23,
    "windspeed" : 23,
    "directionwind" : "s",
    ....   
}
Device Id will be sent as the clientID from the sensor
```

### What I Want

Determine an efficient approach to write batched data to the respective collections in MongoDB based on the provided schema.

For e.g Datasource id : 1 has 20 variables , I have to store each variable in variables collection, and also their corresponding value to the values table with their timestamps. Also keeping in mind the scenario where the same device with id 1 can also send more than 20 variables in future if needed.

### What I Hope To Learn

1. Is the current database schema suitable for efficiently storing and retrieving IoT data? If not, what improvements or alternative schema design would you suggest?
2. Considering the batched data scenario, how can I write the data to the database following the structure mentioned above? Specifically, I need to store each variable in the Variables collection and its corresponding value in the Values collection with timestamps. How can I handle the possibility of the same device sending more than 20 variables in the future?

I would appreciate any guidance or recommendations on optimizing the database schema and efficiently writing batched IoT data to MongoDB. Thank you!